# UDT::send in a for loop sends only once. No error

Tags: c++, c, udp, udp-data-transfer

This sends data only once which seems irrational to me as it is in a for loop:

```
char* hello;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    hello = "Hello world!\n";
    if (UDT::ERROR == UDT::send(client, hello, strlen(hello) + 1, 0))
    {
        cout << "send: " << UDT::getlasterror().getErrorMessage();
    }

}
```

Shouldn't it send data 10 times? I don't understand it. Here is the whole program (it's quite short):

```
int main()
{
    UDTSOCKET client;
    sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(9000);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr);
    memset(&(serv_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

    client = UDT::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // connect to the server, implict bind
    if (UDT::ERROR == UDT::connect(client, (sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)))
    {
        cout << "connect: " << UDT::getlasterror().getErrorMessage();
    }

    char* hello;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        hello = "Hello world!\n";

        if (UDT::ERROR == UDT::send(client, hello, strlen(hello) + 1, 0))
        {
            cout << "send: " << UDT::getlasterror().getErrorMessage();
        }

    }

    UDT::close(client);

    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the server side code. Client is doing sends in a for loop, how is the server side receiving them?

Edit:
In reference to your post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232945/udt-server-buffer-size). If your server code looks like this, it will receive only once. The server is getting the connection from the client then receives once then again waits for connection from a client. But the client keeps sending in a loop. Its just a guess that this is your server code, I could be wrong.

```
while (true)
{
  UDTSOCKET recver = UDT::accept(serv, (sockaddr*)&their_addr, &namelen);

  cout << "new connection: " << inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr) << ":" << ntohs(their_addr.sin_port) << endl;

  if (UDT::ERROR == UDT::recv(recver, data, 100, 0))
  {
    cout << "recv:" << UDT::getlasterror().getErrorMessage() << endl;
    //return 0;
  }
....................
....................
}
```

Comment: Server is receiving in a while(true) loop.

Answer (score 1):

Does it go through the loop 10 times, or only go through the loop once?

I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but I didn't see any kind of `flush` command.  If it goes through the loop 10 times but only sends data once, you might need to flush.

Comment: It goes through the loop 10 times. The library documentation is here: http://udt.sourceforge.net/udt4/index.htm. How should I flush? I am not very good with C/C++. I just followed some code snippets from the documentation.

Comment: How do you determin it only sends one message ? Did you monitor with wireshark ?

Answer (score 1):

Client and server structure doesn't match.

Client sends 10 times inside 1 connection.
Server accepts 10 connections and reads only 1 time inside each one.

Obviously, each connection is simmilar to a container. Data sent but not read after closing a connection is discarded and (of course) not accessible from other connections.